# Should you use a single .bib file to generate various bibliographies?

Tags: bibtex, best-practices

I'm just getting comfortable with BibTex, and I have a question about best practices. It goes like this:

Say I'm teaching a course. I give out an introductory handout at the beginning of the course, in which I lay out the context for the course and reference various articles and other outside works that are not part of the reading list, but are still relevant. At the end of the handout is a reference list. I do this for each unit of study in the course; the point is to provide students with a bunch of relevant material for further reading, for those who want to delve deeper into the subject than just the required reading list.

Is it better to make one large .bib file and cite selectively, depending on what we're studying at a given time, or to make a separate .bib file for each unit of study? The advantage of the former is that it would be easier to generate a cumulative reference sheet at the end of the course, if I so chose; the advantage of the latter is that sources relevant to a given topic would be organized together. **Is there a standard best practice, or does practice vary?**

Comment: If the main advantages are as you identified: switch to `biblatex` and you can use multiple `bib` at the same time. Instant "best of both worlds".

Comment: Of course you can organize a single `.bib` file by collecting all entries for the first unit on top, all entries for the second unit below that, etc. You can use pseudo-comments (any line of text in between entries is ignored in BibTeX) to note where a new unit starts. A downside is that entries used in multiple units cannot easily be organized like this.